# Is the HOME environment variable normally set in Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

To be clear, I'm not asking *can it be set* or *how to set it*, I'm asking *is it already set at all* on a new copy of Windows.  The ideal way to find this out would be to install a fresh copy of Windows on a VM and check, since most of everybody who can answer this question will already have it set ;-)

I need to know if I can depend on it always being there.  (I understand that these can be unset, but if you know how to do that you know you're asking for trouble.)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No, it is not. The closest equivalents in Windows NT are `%UserProfile%` and `%HomeDrive%%HomePath%` (note that they may point to different locations – the profile is always local, while the home can point to a network share).

Comment: When I try to create a folder with `mkdir %HomeDrive%%HomePath%/MyFolder` on Windows with PowerShell it just creates a folder with that literal name including percent signs.

Comment: @Aaron: If you're in PowerShell, then use the PowerShell syntax for environment variables, not the Cmd.exe syntax.

Answer (score 9):

No.

The equivalent environment variables that *are* set are `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`.

Answer (score 6):

There's also `%LOCALAPPDATA%` (never roaming) and `%APPDATA%` (can roam). You're not supposed to write to `%UserProfile%` directly, and you can't predict the relative path from `%LOCALAPPDATA%` to `%APPDATA%` (could be localized).

Comment: `%LocalAppData%` seems to be added in Vista; older versions have the directory but it can be only found using the shell API, not envvars.